# How can i do DOSBox Assembly mouse events

Tags: assembly, dos, dosbox

I've just started to learn the "assembly" language.

How can I print "Hello World" every time I left-click with the mouse and print "Bad World" every right-click on DOSBox.

Comment: DOS doesn't come with mouse support. You will need to provide your own driver. Each one has a different programming interface, so see its documentation for how to do this. This is not a good project for someone just beginning to learn assembly, by the way. Start with outputting some values to the screen, maybe reading some keyboard input.

Comment: It contains too much detail, I have difficulty understanding,But thanks for the redirect. @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez.

Comment: Hasan, you only need procedure `GetMouseState` (http://stackoverflow.com/a/37795357/3298930)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found the solution to the problem.

```
  program SEGMENT
  ASSUME CS:program,DS:program
  ORG 100h
```

First we need to call mouse cursor.Check for catalog http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33.html

```
  start:
  MOV AX,01
  INT 33h
```

http://stanislavs.org/helppc/int_33-5.html
We will not use other bits except the last two bits, so we made the rest zero with AND operator.

```
  loop:
  MOV AX,03
  INT 33h
  AND BX,3h
```

We compare the rotated value,and send the function according to the result

```
  CMP BX,1
  JE  left
  CMP BX,2
  JE  right

  cmp BX,0
  je  endss
  cmp bx,3 
  je  endss
  right:
  MOV DX,OFFSET stringright
  MOV AH,09h
  INT 21h


  jmp endss
  left:
  MOV DX,OFFSET stringleft
  MOV AH,09h
  INT 21h

  endss:

  jmp loop
  stringright DB "Right Clicked $"
  stringleft DB "Left Clicked $" 

  INT 20h
  program ENDS
  END start
```